# Batch arguments for SSH Secure Shell in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, ssh, shell, batch, arguments

I installed SSH Secure Shell to connect to my remote server, and I want to automate the process of updating my website. I was going to make a batch script to automatically push and pull from my site onto my computer, but I don't know any of the command line arguments for SSH. I tried looking them up, but got nowhere. Can anyone help?

If you need specifics, I'm aiming to make two batch files; one that erases my local files and pulls them from my webserver while logging on to the server, and one that erases the webserver's files and pushes them from my local system while also logging on.

Also, I don't want any suggestions for alternative SSH clients like PuTTy, there's a reason I'm using SSH Secure Shell. (And yes, it's because I'm a student.)

Comment: For clarification, I believe the OP is talking about [this program](http://sils.unc.edu/it-services/servers/using-ssh) in particular. Unfortunately, the program is very buggy on Windows 7. Didn't play with the compatibility modes though.

Comment: Yes krowe, that's unfortunately correct.